# How to write html/javascript in python for making web application using flask?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, bokeh

I have written one javascript file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300>
  <script >
     var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
     var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
     var cw=canvas.width;
     var ch=canvas.height;

     var PI=Math.PI;
     var PI2=PI*2;
     var cx=150;
     var cy=150;
     var r=80;
     var min=PI*.60;
     var max=PI2+PI*.40;
     var percent=50;

     ctx.lineCap='round';
     ctx.font='24px verdana';
     ctx.textAlign='center';
     ctx.textBaseline='middle';
     ctx.fillStyle='gray';

     drawGuage();

     function drawGuage(){
       ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
       // draw full guage outline
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,min,max);
       ctx.strokeStyle='lightgray';
       ctx.lineWidth=15;
       ctx.stroke();
       // draw percent indicator
       ctx.beginPath();
       ctx.arc(cx,cy,r,min,min+(max-min)*percent/100);
       ctx.strokeStyle='red';
       ctx.lineWidth=6;
       ctx.stroke();
       ctx.fillText(percent+'%',cx,cy);
     }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And it is giving me output like this

[image: LINK]

This value will change and I am able to return this value using pandas dataframe where it is returning my value.

```
var percent=50;
```

I want to code this same thing in python where I am using flask and var percent should take my pandas dataframe return value.

I am new to javascript in python and I am not able to understand how to write the same code in python using HTML and javascript and flask calling my py file.

Comment: "Generally" you can't, because your python server code, which generates the html (flask) and the browser frontend which executes the javascript (the code you've written above) are two independent processes that "have nothing to do with each other" (besides that flask generates the code that is run on the client). If you want to update a variable client side you somehow need to get the new value from your server to the client. There are many frameworks which can help you with that. Have you already decided on one or do you want to code from scratch?

Comment: I have not decided on any framework yet, actually, I have no idea about this. Can you please guide @syntonym

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render HTML templates using Python Flask app. You need to maintain the 2 folders in your parent directory (where the python flask app resides), templates (for html) and static (for js files).

Either include your javascript code in your html template or have it in a separate static folder. You need to have a jinja template which will be replaced with the percent value. Then pass percent value returned from dataframe to render_template('index.html', value=value).

I found this post really useful.
http://www.patricksoftwareblog.com/tag/javascript/